# Browser won't show HTML File

Tags: java, html, swing, runnable

I've got these two classes which are to be part of a larger project, but for some odd reason, the browser will not show the HTML file when I run `main()`.

Here are the two classes:

Main:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BrowserFrame browser = new BrowserFrame();

        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
        Thread browserThread = new Thread();

        mainFrame.getContentPane().add(browser);
        mainFrame.setSize(550,550);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        browserThread.start();
        browser.setVisible(true);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

BrowserFrame

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
import javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet;

public class BrowserFrame extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public void BrowserFrame()  {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() 
            {
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL("file:///C:/PersonalWorkSpace/PrivateEyes/html/test.html");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            JEditorPane jEditorPane = new JEditorPane();
            jEditorPane.setEditable(false);

            JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jEditorPane);

            HTMLEditorKit kit = new HTMLEditorKit();
            jEditorPane.setEditorKit(kit);

            StyleSheet styleSheet = kit.getStyleSheet();
            styleSheet.addRule("body {color:#000; font-family:times; margin: 4px;}");
            styleSheet.addRule("h1 {color: blue;}");
            styleSheet.addRule("h2 {color: #ff0000;}");

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(jEditorPane);


            try {
                jEditorPane.setPage(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            jEditorPane.setVisible(true);
            jScrollPane.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println("Browser Window Run");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Some of my code may come across as a little erratic/weird, but that's because I was trying some things and some remnants are left.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `void` in front of BrowserFrame(). It is considered as a method instead of a constructor.

Comment: Oh my God! To think I'd spent all this time adding bits and taking bits away and it was one word I had added out of habit. Will accept your answer once the timer runs down.

Comment: I hate when that happens, but I usually do find a few bugs in the process that would have caused headaches later on =)